# Cannot build Lightswitch project after adding a datasource

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am trying to add a sql database to my lightswitch application project however when I do and try to build or run the project I get .net errors such as
'type name system.datetime does not exist in lightswitchapplication.system' and other errors that are similar.

When I do remove the datasource and build the project it builds successfully.Why could it be that my existing datasources do not throw errors?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried to 'Clean Solution' or exit out of Visual Studio and re-open then re-build?

Comment: it will clean sometimes but it wont build at all. I have tried exiting visual studio but still no luck

Comment: have you tried creating a new Project to see if this solves the issue or does it happen on each Project?